# PostgreSQL query none match criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table (with about 100 million rows) as follows

```
identifier       bigint
active           boolean
extraInformation character varying(100)
```

The data can and will have several rows where active is false for every identifier, but there must always be exactly one where active is true for every identifier.

There was a bug that caused all active flags to be set to false for certain identifiers.

I therefore need a query as follows:

***Show all identifiers that have all their active flags set to false***

Comment: are identifier and active the column names? You can use a group by i think

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are on 9.4, you can use this:

```
select identifier 
from the_table
group by identifier
having count(*) = count(*) filter (where not active);
```

For older versions:

```
select identifier 
from the_table
group by identifier
having count(*) = count(case when not active then 1 end);
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7423e/2

Comment: Much better than my suggestion, I'll remove my answer